# Trouble focusing on Story 1 because Story 2 seems so much better. How to get the next Story 1 chapter done?

Tags: creative-writing, chapters

I have 3 stories that I rotate between when writing the new chapters, one of which I just recently finished the first chapter. This new story('Tech Vs Magic'* ) seems really good to me right after finishing the first chapter. I thought I was just on a 'writer's high' sort of thing, but now it's 2 days after finishing the first chapter and I still can't focus on the next book('Magical Space Adventures'*) in the rotation I need to write.

How can I focus on this next story chapter? Should I just put Magical Space Adventures on hold and keep writing Tech Vs Magic until I can focus on the next story again?

Not a duplicate of [How can I focus on writing one book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/51485/how-can-i-focus-on-writing-one-book), I need help un-focusing on one book and then focusing on another.

---

*- not actual story titles

Comment: If you are on a roll writing Tech vs Magic, why switch? I would stick with one story until you reach writer's block, go to a different story, and come back in a week or two to the original story.

Comment: Could you clarify: Why do you feel you need to be working on multiple stories at all? Do you have deadlines?

Comment: @WeckarE., I have no deadlines, I just don't want the 4-5 people who read my stories have to wait an insanely long time before the next chapter goes up.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b I'd imagine having to wait longer for more of your favourite would have the opposite effect. But you know you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods of writing several stories/books at the same time.
So far you have used the 'every next day you do a bit on the next book'.
An other that works for many people is 'work on one book till you either get stuck or get a good idea for one of the others and then switch and work till you either again get stuck or get inspiration for an other of our books.'

And it is also very much allowed to mix the two systems, as long as you are happy with the results. Like pull out the story you are not happy writing further, go over what you have already written and either edit or leave alone while you put it back and pull out one of the others.

It was reading interviews with my favorite writers I got this information. But I am do not remember who wrote the actual advice. Likely this is a mix of several.

Answer (score 1):

Unless creative energy is something you have great control over, I say ride the wave, while looking for opportunities to jump back to story one.  Writing the next chapter just cuz may leave your readers disappointed.

Maintaining discipline without squelching energy is the main struggle here. I know I envy those who have mastered it.

Personally, I find that writing is writing. Like any craft, it's the doing that builds the skill. So whatever keeps you doing will make you stronger at it. Then discipline comes in when I don't have extra motivation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not killing the temptation of working on Story 2 first.
Make a pact with yourself that you will write one chapter of Story 2 (or two) and then go back to Story 1.

This way you will be enough motivated for writing both of these stories.